# using dct for embeding watermark on gocv

Tags: opencv, go, watermark, dct

Is there any examples using dct for embeding watermark with [gocv](https://github.com/hybridgroup/gocv)?

Answer (score 0):

gocv isn't that great of a solution for watermarking. Use the standard [`Draw`](https://pkg.go.dev/image/draw#Op.Draw) library instead.